# Accessing a member of a class using a string variable with the name of the member

Tags: php, oop

**Short Version:** Why can't we access a function like this:

```
$b = "simple_print()";
$obj->$b;
```

**Complete Version:**

Suppose we have a class User defined like this:

```
class User {
    public $name;

    function simple_print() {
        echo "Just Printing" . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Now if a create an User object and set the name of it we can print its name using

```
$obj = new User;
$obj->name = "John";
echo $obj->name;
```

Although it is strange we also can do something like this in order to print "John":

```
$a = "name";
echo $obj->$a;
```

But we can't access a function using the same idea:

```
$b = "simple_print()";
$obj->$b;
```

Why? **Shouldn't it work the same way?**

Also, does anyone know **what is it called?** I tried to look for "accessing a member through a variable" and "using a method through a variable with the name of it" but I didn't find anything related to this.

*Extra info: The version of PHP I'm using is: PHP version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close, but made a small logical mistake. Try this instead:

```
$b = 'simple_print';
$obj->$b();
```

This is because the method is accessed by it's name, which is `simple_print`, not `simple_print()`. The execution is triggered by the parenthesis, but that is *not* part of the name, so of how you access the method.

Here is a short example:

```
<?php
class Test
{
  public function simple_print() {
    echo "Hello world!\n";
  }
}
$object = new Test;
$method = 'simple_print';
$object->$method();
```

As expected it creates the output `Hello world!` if executed on CLI.

Comment: Indeed it works, although it still seems a little odd to me.
Also, imo it doesn't seem to be a good practice (even being really useful in some cases), is it as secure as checking with an if statement to see the content of variable $a and then selecting the right method? If so, there isn't a problem using it, right? -besides the readability loss-

Comment: I won't start a discussion about what is odd or a good practice since I do not practice religion in IT. :-) About the checking of the content by means of a conditional: you can do that, but it only makes sense if you have methods you do _not_ want to expose that way. In such case I would advise to redesign your class and use an interface or a limited parent class instead. Otherwise it is safe, since you get a runtime exception if you address a method that does not exist. You can even catch and handle that exception which is elegant.